# Returning values from ElasticSearch document on the basis of value of a single field

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to return values from `Elasticsearch` **document** using `SpringBoot` application in `JAVA`. 
Here is my code for the search

```
//1
 SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("recipe1")
            .addDocValueField("Title")
            .setSize(10)
            .get();
//2
 SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch()
            .setIndices("recipe1")
            .setTypes("default")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setFetchSource(new String[]{"Title"}, null)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
            .setSize(10).execute().actionGet();
```

My document has multiple fields in it but I want to return all the fields where the **Title** field has the same value as passed to `Elasticsearch`.

I also used this code but not getting the exact output. rather in some cases(I've tried a lot) it returns all of the values whether matching with the searched title or not. 
    I'm a newbie in `Elasticsearch`. I know I'm putting the query wrong but unable to find the specific query. Please help me figure it out.

**My Stored data in Elasticsearch document. It is in the form of JSON which I need as JSON in response**

```
  {
    "_index" : "recipe1",
    "_type" : "default",
    "_id" : "AWyPqNkb3frYFJ2__B8b",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "message" : "[{\"id\":15,\"recipe_url\":\"https://www.example.com\",\"Channel\":\"Recipe\",\"Title\":\"Jamoo recipe\",\"Rating\":{\"id\":null,\"ratingValue\":4.625,\"bestRating\":5,\"worstRating\":1,\"ratingCount\":8},\"Timings\":{\"id\":null,\"cookTime\":\"PT5M\",\"prepTime\":\"PT5M\",\"totalTime\":\"PT10M\"},\"Author\":{\"id\":null,\"eval\":false,\"value\":\"JAMSHAID\",\"url\":\"https://www.example.com\",\"additionalInfo\":\"Recipe from Good Food magazine, \",\"description\":\"Substitute potatoes with pulses for a healthy alternative mash with a chunky texture\",\"published\":\"November 2011\"},\"Publication\":{\"id\":null,\"eval\":false,\"value\":\"\",\"url\":\"\",\"additionalInfo\":\"\",\"published\":\"\"},\"Nutrition\":\"per serving\",\"NutritionContents\":{\"id\":0,\"kcal\":183,\"fat\":\"5g\",\"saturates\":\"1g\",\"carbs\":\"25g\",\"sugars\":\"3g\",\"fibre\":\"7g\",\"protein\":\"11g\",\"salt\":\"0.84g\"},\"SkillLevel\":\"Easy\",\"Ingredients\":[\"1 tbsp olive oil, plus a drizzle to serve (optional)\",\"2 x 400g cans cannellini beans, rinsed and drained\",\"2 tbsp pesto\"],\"MakingMethod\":[\"Heat the oil in a large saucepan. Add the beans and cook for 3-4 mins until hot through. Lightly mash with a potato masher for a chunky texture. Stir through the pesto and season. To serve, drizzle with a little olive oil, if you like.\"],\"Keywords\":[\"Cannellini bean\",\"Cannellini beans\",\"Mash\",\"Beans\",\"Super healthy\",\"Pulses\",\"5-a-day\",\"Low fat\",\"Diet\",\"Dieting\",\"Side dish\",\"Bangers and mash\",\"Sausage and mash\",\"Texture\",\"Fireworks\",\"Pesto\",\"Easy\",\"Vegetarian\",\"Healthy\",\"Bonfire Night\"],\"Category\":[\"Side dish\",\"Dinner\"],\"Cousine\":\"Pakisttani\",\"Servings\":\"Serves 4\"}]"
    }
  },
```

**Complete Method**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "stringSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getitem(@RequestParam("data") String title) {
    client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().get();

    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("recipe1")
            .addDocValueField("Title")
            .setSize(10)
            .get();


    SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch()
            .setIndices("recipe1")
            .setTypes("default")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
          //  .setFetchSource(new String[]{"Title"}, null)
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(title))
            .setSize(10).execute().actionGet();
    return scrollResp.toString();
}
```

**Inserting data in Elasticsearch**

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("message", content1.toString());
```

where content1 is a `StringBuffer`.

```
Client client1 = new Config().client();
            System.out.println(client.toString());
            client1.prepareIndex("recipe1", "default").setSource(jsonObject).get();
```

**Stack Trace after suggested changes**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.source(IndexRequest.java:464)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.source(IndexRequest.java:389)
at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder.setSource(IndexRequestBuilder.java:131)
at com.techno.homes.search.ServicesPackage.MessageConsumerService.main(MessageConsumerService.java:88)
```

**Data in Elasticsearch document after changes**

```
{
    "_index" : "recipe",
    "_type" : "default",
    "_id" : "AWyUshs9VwfAdwghb9LK",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "[{\"Timings\":{\"totalTime\":\"PT10M\",\"cookTime\":\"PT5M\",\"id\":null,\"prepTime\":\"PT5M\"},\"SkillLevel\":\"Easy\",\"Keywords\":[\"Cannellini bean\",\"Cannellini beans\",\"Mash\",\"Beans\",\"Super healthy\",\"Pulses\",\"5-a-day\",\"Low fat\",\"Diet\",\"Dieting\",\"Side dish\",\"Bangers and mash\",\"Sausage and mash\",\"Texture\",\"Fireworks\",\"Pesto\",\"Easy\",\"Vegetarian\",\"Healthy\",\"Bonfire Night\"],\"Category\":[\"Side dish\",\"Dinner\"],\"Nutrition\":\"per serving\",\"MakingMethod\":[\"Heat the oil in a large saucepan. Add the beans and cook for 3-4 mins until hot through. Lightly mash with a potato masher for a chunky texture. Stir through the pesto and season. To serve, drizzle with a little olive oil, if you like.\"],\"Cousine\":\"British\",\"Channel\":\"Recipe\",\"Rating\":{\"bestRating\":5,\"ratingValue\":4.625,\"id\":null,\"ratingCount\":8,\"worstRating\":1},\"Ingredients\":[\"1 tbsp olive oil, plus a drizzle to serve (optional)\",\"2 x 400g cans cannellini beans, rinsed and drained\",\"2 tbsp pesto\"],\"Servings\":\"Serves 4\",\"Title\":\"Bean & pesto mash\",\"Publication\":{\"eval\":false,\"additionalInfo\":\"\",\"id\":null,\"published\":\"\",\"value\":\"\",\"url\":\"\"},\"recipe_url\":\"https://www.techno-homes.com/recipes/1742637/bean-and-pesto-mash\",\"Author\":{\"eval\":false,\"additionalInfo\":\"Recipe from Good Food magazine, \",\"description\":\"Substitute potatoes with pulses for a healthy alternative mash with a chunky texture\",\"id\":null,\"published\":\"November 2011\",\"value\":\"Techno Homes\",\"url\":\"https://www.techno-homes.com/publication/good-food-0\"},\"id\":64,\"NutritionContents\":{\"kcal\":183,\"sugars\":\"3g\",\"salt\":\"0.84g\",\"carbs\":\"25g\",\"protein\":\"11g\",\"fat\":\"5g\",\"saturates\":\"1g\",\"id\":0,\"fibre\":\"7g\"}}]" : ""
    }
```

Comment: While ingesting the data, you are setting message filed content as string. So the result will be string. You need to parse the message field content as Json object.

Comment: Actually, the query you supplied is: QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(). Meaning you are asking to get all documents that are placed on index: recipe1 with type: default.

setFetchSource(new String[]{"Title"}, null) means that instead of querying all fields of each document you just want to select the title field from each document.

In order to select only documents with a specific value use an appropriate 'term' or 'match' query instead of QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery().

Comment: @MichaelKopaniov would you please provide some resources for that>

Comment: @hkulekci I'm okay with receiving a String back as well but I'm unable to search it

Comment: You mean, full text search on string. What is your mapping for the index? Did you set message filed as text or keyword?

Comment: I want to perform the search in `Elasticsearch` document and return the results in `String` format. the result should be having the title same as input `String` which I'm passing as a parameter to the method

Comment: @hkulekci I've updated the question. Please have a look again

Comment: My friend on your document there is no `Title` field. There is only one field and it is `message`. So you need to use some JSON parsing while ingesting the document.

Comment: @hkulekci I've added insertion code to the question. Please have a look and suggest how I should change that to get it correct

Comment: parse the `content1.toString()` instead of pitting in message field.

Comment: but `JSONObject` needs a `key` to store the data in it. How am I supposed to achieve that?

Comment: Yes I mean, parse the content1 string and put this json object result into setSource() method as parameter.

Comment: I'm having an error while content1.toString is passed to setSource() which is mentioned in the code. If I'm passing the jsonObject, it doesn't produce the eroor

Comment: @hkulekci I've updated the question. My data is being stored in that format now. Please have a look. THanks